# partial derivative of log likelihood function

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, random-effects-model, fisher-scoring

I am trying to find $\partial/\partial \theta \log \ L $ where $L = \pi^y(1-\pi)^{1-y},  \pi = \frac{\exp(X \beta)}{1+\exp(X \beta)}, \ X$ is $ N(\mu,\sigma^2) \  \& \  y$ is binary.

I first plugged in $\pi$ in terms of $X, \beta$ then considered $\log L$ and simplified. This is what I got after simplifying, $\log L$,

$\log L =\ell = {y X\beta -\log(1+\exp(X\beta))- \log (2\pi \sigma^2) - \frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$. How can I take  $\partial/\partial \theta \log L $ when $\ X$ is $ N(\mu,\sigma^2) $. Do I have to consider GLM approach? Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your notation leaves something to be desired. First, you're likely wanting to take a derivative in $\beta$, not $\theta$. $X$ can be whatever you want, random or otherwise, however, it is constant with respect to the partial derivative in $\beta$. So differentiate as if it were constant with respect to $\beta$.

Comment: Did you mean that we do not have to worry about X being normally distributed. I was thinking about GLM approach using a link function, but I am not sure how I can do it. If x being considered as a constant when we differentiate wrt to $\beta$, which means there is no effect from X when we estimate parameters using MLE approach. Is it correct?  please provide some more steps. Thanks.